# What is Mass Production?

Tags: exominer

The Exocorp Idle Miner Universe game Exominer, requires the completion of 'Mass Production' to complete rank 10.

Previously all the requirements have been pretty specific, refining a specific amount of a certain type of ore or producing certain quantities of a specific product.

[image: Mass Production]

This one seems vague and I have no idea what it wants me to do.